# Cannot create an object through actionscript

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I created MovieClip, "Exported it for ActionScript" with the same name. It's okay when I create an object visually, by dragging it to the stage but when using `var smth:* = new myClass()` an error occurs. There is an error because I have some code in the MovieClip I exported, and it involves the Stage. It happens so that stage is not instantiated at the moment of running code? I mean, I'm creating the object on the second frame so it's seems kinda impossible. When (in the MovieClip) I write `trace(stage);` output is `null`. As I said, there is no problem when creating object visually. Ladies and gentlemen, what the...?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I follow what you're saying, you don't have a reference to the `stage` right-away inside your `MovieClip` subclass? This happens if the `MovieClip` is not attached to the stage or another `DisplayObjectContainer` that is already attached to it (somewhere up the Display-list chain).

One way to verify if the stage is available AND to execute your code WHEN IT IS available, is a little code snippet often found in FlashDevelop projects:

```
public function Main():void {
    stage ? init() : addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
}

private function init(e:Event = null):void {
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
    // entry point
}
```

So if the `stage` IS found, it immediatly triggers the `init()` method (without arguments), otherwise it will wait for when it is added to the stage (or some other DisplayObjectContainer that is already attached), which will pass in the `Event` parameter when it makes use of `init(e:Event)` as a callback method.

Answer (score 1):

```
import flash.events.Event;
```

In the constructor of the class add an eventListener for the stage to be added.

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, myFunction);
```

then just create an eventListener with the name init and with an event as parameter.

```
function myFunction(e : Event) : void
{
    this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, myFunction);

    // execute code here
}
```

The removeEventListener is required, don't forget to remove it! A bug in flash will trigger the event added to stage twice, so if you don't want to execute the code twice, you have to remove it.

Comment: oh, thanks. it works. however, whenever i write `MovieClip(this.root)` there is an error which says that AS was not able to convert `Stage` to `MovieClip`. Why is that?

Comment: Please ask this in a separate question, that way others users can find the solution faster using search :-).